# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method problem

Tags: java

I tried hard to make it. But I've got an error message
"Student is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) in Comparable
class Student extends Person {"

```
abstract class Person implements Comparable {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    private int id;

    public Student(String name, int id) {
        super(name);

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(id);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        if (this.id < s.getId()) {
            return -1;
        }else if (this.id > s.getId()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        if (this.id < s.getId()) {
            return -1;
        }else if (this.id > s.getId()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

this is where I think having a problem...

Comment: Your `Comparable` is a *raw* generic. Don't use raw generics. See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5221149)

Comment: Why do you put `implements Comparable` on `Person`, when you can't compare two persons of different subclasses anyway? E.g. comparing a `Student` and a `Teacher` would throw `ClassCastException` --- Make `Student` do the `implements Comparable`, not `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by @Andreas, make `Student implements Comparable`, not `Person`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Student> {
    private int id;

    public Student(String name, int id) {
        super(name);

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(id);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.id, o.id);
    }
}
```

## Demo

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("Abc", 321));
        list.add(new Student("Xyz", 12));
        list.add(new Student("Mnp", 123));
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[12, 123, 321]
```